# CSS menu with hover that changes the entire frame picture

Tags: html, css

I made a CSS menu that should replace the other menu on hover (should replace the center image and the hover on the menu links). My idea was using the entire center as background images with the buttons so the menu and the center is the same image.

When hovering vertically the menu works fine. But after hovering another link I can't go back up as the links are not active as they must be hiding due to the top margin (or something like that). You can see the menu at the bottom (blue buttons which turns red at bottom):

http://www.israelijewel.com/1.html

Comment: The link text is missing on the bottom menu.

Comment: There shouldn't be a link text actually, just the images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

weird pattern to do that, why don't you do this:

inside each "a" inside .home-gallery, put the image you want in the center with position: absolute;display:none; and position that usings it's absolute position. Then you can make it appear at the center doing something like:

```
.mofet-link:hover {
  //set you button to red here
}
.mofet-link:hover .inside_image {
  display: block;
}
```

you should set .home-gallery a position:relative; attribute too